# Catalog product view page is not showing particular product in magento?

Tags: magento, view, magento-1.9, product, catalog

suddenly, catalog product view page is not showing any product. only link is working but  showing empty page.

What i need to do?

Comment: is it showing some error message ?  also please check magento logs for more information

Comment: nothing happens suddenly dude you have messed up ..

Comment: After clearing index management, catalog product page is started working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

For **simple product**, check if you have *status*: enabled, *inventory qty* >= 1 and *stock availability*: in stock. For **configurable product** also check if you have *status*: enabled, *visibility*: catalog, search, and that you have at least one associated simple product active. Refresh indexes and cache, then check your frontend.

If you used a Dataflow Profile to run an import job from a CSV file and either the profile or the file contents were formated incorrectly, then some of your product attribute values are off and your products are not showing.

Also, check your browser console for errors that might break your HTML/CSS/JavaScript when the page is rendering. Check your browser extensions too, use different browser, different PC and/or different IP.